# Magento2 controller response for iframe

Tags: magento2, iframe

I'm working on creating iframe in magento2.

Content of this iframe should be a custom form, which exists in one of templates.

I made following:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/iframe/show') ?>" frameborder="0" style="height:75px;"></iframe>
```

It means that my controller `module/iframe/show` should return me a content for this form, but I don't know what exactly should return/render/output my controller. Now I can receive only full rendered page in this iframe. It means that probably block side is working well and **i need only proper controller code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer in default magento modules.

Some variables (block_name, form_id) were replaced with strings to clearly understand the idea.

```
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Iframe\Show'
        )->setFormId(
            'form_id'
        )->setIsAjax(
            true
        )->toHtml()
    );
```